# Preservation of a Cartesian structure for a permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

The notion of a Cartesian structure for a permutation group appears in this [presentation](http://math.sjtu.edu.cn/conference/Bannai/2017/data/20171114B/slides.pdf) on slide 10 (or 45). What I do not understand is what should it mean that a permutation group preserve such a struture?

To cite the relevant definitions:

> A *Cartesian structure* on $\Omega$ is an identification of $\Omega$ with $A^d$, where $A$ is some set. We can regard $A$ an an "alphabet", and $A^d$ as the set of all words of length $d$ over the alphabet $A$. Then $A^d$ is a metric space, with the *Hamming metric* [...]: the distance between two words is the number of positions in which they differ.
>   A Cartesian structure is non-trivial if $|A|>1$ and $d > 1$. Let $G$ be a primitive permutation group on $\Omega$. We say that $G$ is *basic* if it preserves no non-trivial Cartesian structure on $\Omega$.

What should it mean that a Cartesian structure is preserved? If $\Omega = A^d$ for some $|A| > 1$, $d > 1$ then tupels (or words) are mapped to tupels (or words), so what is (or is not) preserved here?

Answer (score 2):

It means that there is no injective homomorphism $G\to\operatorname{Isom}(\Omega)$.

That is, look at all the possible actions of $G$ on $\Omega$. If there is some action such that the Hamming distance between two words, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, is equal to the Hamming distance between $\alpha^g$ and $\beta^g$ for every element $g\in G$, then we say that $G$ preserves the Cartesian structure on $\Omega$.

To give an example, consider a set $A$ and identify $\Omega$ with $A^1$ — i.e. all words of length one. Then the Hamming distance is:

$$H_d(a,b) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & a=b \\
1 & a\ne b
\end{cases}$$

Thus any permutation group $G$ is *not basic* on $\Omega$.

Comment: You mean your example $G$ is *non-basic* at it preserves the structure, i.e. $\alpha^g = \beta^g \Leftrightarrow \alpha = \beta$, or not?

Comment: Yes, of course. Typo fixed.

Answer (score 2):

To say that $G$ preserves the structure $\Omega = A^d$ means that the action of $G$ on $\Omega$ is equivalent to a subgroup of the full automorphism group of the structure $A^d$.

This full automorphism group is a wreath product ${\rm Sym}(A) \wr {\rm Sym}(d)$. The base group is generated by those permutations that just permute the entries in each individual coordinate of $A^d$. This is the direct product of $d$ copies of ${\rm Sym}(A)$, one for each coordinate. A complement in the wreath product isomorphic to ${\rm Sym}(d)$ permutes the entries of each element of $A^d$. For example, if $d=2$, a generator of the complement would map each $(a,b)$ to $(b,a)$.

Comment: Just one question, how do you know that every bijection $\varphi : A^d \to A^d$ could be decomposed as such a wreath product? That $\varphi \in \mbox{Sym}(A) \wr \mbox{Sym}(d)$ gives a bijection is clear, but the other direction does not seem obvious to me...

Comment: It is not true that every bijection $A^d \to A^d$ can be decomposed in this way. I am saying that those that preserve the structure can. Personally I tend to think of that as a definitrion of preserving the structure. The point is that the subgroups of ${\rm Sym}(A) \wr {\rm Sym}(d)$ that satisfy certain conditions act primitively on $\Omega = A^d$, and these are examples of non-basic groups that arise in the O'Nan-Scott theorem.

Comment: But what else should an element of $\mbox{Aut}(A^d)$ be? What is the structure that has to be preserved? There is no concatenation or anything on $A^d$ per se...